# Safe_L2 v1.4 on Base is Unsupported by the Safe App and Safe SDK

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe

Our app deploy Multisigs on behalf of the users and recently we did migrated to Base. What is happening is that Multisigs created using Safe Proxy Factory v1.3 + SafeL2 v1.4 is marked as Unsupported by the Safe App. And when users try to send transaction inside our app that uses Safe Protocol Kit, it returns:

```
Error trying to execute transaction: Contract-transaction-
hash=0x33d7b22790fd17f... does not match provided contract-tx-hash=0x9caf29bb1f0d6f6519...
```

Users are really pissed off and we have no idea how to solve this. These are some of the contracts affected.

0xF4eBBAd31F11A10A17c897373C81EFDCf58D9Ae9

0x0966caf922e71c95f6EF12648395EaE5602E2F6d

The users are also unable to move any fund or transfer anything cause the Safe App itself doesn't recognize its own contracts deployed.

[image]